# Matplotlib: How to make two histograms have the same bin width?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've spent some time searching the interwebs for an answer for this, and I have tried looking all over SO for an answer too, but I think I do not have the correct terminology down... Please excuse me if this is a duplicate of some known problem, I'd happily delete my post and refer to that post instead!

In any case, I am trying to plot two histograms on the same figure in Matplotlib. My two data sources are lists of 500 elements long. To provide an illustration of the problem I am facing, please see the following image:

[image: Uneven histograms]

As you can see, the histogram has uneven bin sizes under default parameters, even though the number of bins is the same. I would like to guarantee that the bin widths for both histograms are the same. Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think a consistent way that will easily work for most cases, without having to worry about what is the distribution range for each of your datasets, will be to put the datasets together into a big one, determine the bins edges and then plot:

```
a=np.random.random(100)*0.5 #a uniform distribution
b=1-np.random.normal(size=100)*0.1 #a normal distribution 
bins=np.histogram(np.hstack((a,b)), bins=40)[1] #get the bin edges
plt.hist(a, bins)
plt.hist(b, bins)
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted both answers, but this one definitely provides the clearest instruction on how to do it the data-driven way. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

You should use `bins` from the values returned by `hist`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

foo = np.random.normal(loc=1, size=100) # a normal distribution
bar = np.random.normal(loc=-1, size=10000) # a normal distribution

_, bins, _ = plt.hist(foo, bins=50, range=[-6, 6], normed=True)
_ = plt.hist(bar, bins=bins, alpha=0.5, normed=True)
```

[image: Two matplotlib histograms with same binning]

Comment: If you use this without setting the range, the second histogram can get chopped off at the ends. This is because the returned bins are the edges of the bins in the original figure, which might not include all of the second histogram's data. Something like `bins=len(bins)-1` might work (the `-1` because there is one more bin edge than there are bins), but then you might have some alignment issue.

Answer (score 17):

I guess you can use the range parameter together with the bin parameter to come up with the same bin size for both data sets.

```
plt.hist(x, bins=n, range=(a,b))
```

where if you keep the ratio of `(b-a)/n` the same, you should end up with the same bin sizes.

Comment: you need to specify the range here which is not necessary in CT Zhu answer.

Comment: But in CT Zhu answer you need numpy